# for-loop and object control

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to add elements to an array. The elements of the array are of a custom class called variable. In the problematic for loop, it basically adds the last element trying to be added throughout the loop. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;

public class ThiefsDilemma2{

public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList values = new ArrayList(args.length/2);
    Valuable[] array = new Valuable[args.length/2];

    if(args.length%2 ==1){  

        int weight = Integer.parseInt(args[args.length-1]);
        boolean room = true;
        int tracker = 0;
        //problem!!!! Adds the last element throughout the loop
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length/2; i++){
            array[i] = new Valuable(
                            Integer.parseInt(args[args.length/2+i]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < args.length/2; i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

        while(values.size() > 0 && room){
            int lightest = 100000;
            double value = 0.0;
            int index = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            for(Object p: values){

            Valuable test = (Valuable)p;

            //System.out.println(test);
                if(test.getWeight() < lightest && !test.beenUsed()){
                    lightest = test.getWeight();
                    //System.out.println(lightest);
                }
                if(test.getValue() > value && !test.beenUsed()){
                    index = counter;
                    value = test.getValue();
                    //System.out.println(value);
                }
                else if(test.getValue() == value || !test.beenUsed()){
                    if(test.getWeight() <= test.getWeight()){
                        index = counter;
                    }
                }

                counter++;

            }

            //System.out.println(counter + "   " + lightest + "    " + value);

            Valuable p = ((Valuable)(values.get(index)));
            p.used();


            if(lightest > weight){ room = false;}

            else{
                if(p.getWeight() <= weight){
                    weight -= p.getWeight();
                }

                System.out.println(p);
                values.remove(p);

            }   


        }
        }
    }

    public static class Valuable{

        private static double value;
        private static int weight;
        private static boolean used = false;

        public Valuable(int top, int bottum){
            value = ((double)top/(double)bottum);
            weight = bottum;
            //System.out.println(weight + "    " + value);
        }

        public static double getValue(){
            return value;
        }

        public static int getWeight(){
            return weight;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return value + " " + weight;
        }

        public static void used(){
            used = true;
        }

        public static boolean beenUsed(){
            return used;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  If so you should tag it as such.

Comment: please describe expected behavior

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that all data members of `Valuable` are `static`. This means that they are shared by all instances of the class:

```
private static double value;
private static int weight;
private static boolean used = false;
```

Remove the `static` qualifiers from the data members, and from the getter functions.